# Node.JS | Какой тип функции лучше?

Tags: node.js, функции, typescript

Я рассматривая **Python** увидел в частых циклах **range**. Она позволяет несколько раз провести цикл сколько установлено в диапазоне. Я **JavaScript**-ер, и цикл, бывает, что нужно, повторять в установленном диапазоне, хотя это особо много кода писать:

> `for (let i = **from**; i < **to**; i += **step**)`.

А на **Python** можно реализовать это вот так:

> `for i in range(**from**, **to**, **step**)`

Просто и быстро. Я решил сделать такую функцию на **TypeScript**, и получилось. Она работала так: спрашивается три аргумента: "from"; "to"; "step", и создаётся массив чисел. Потом с помощью цикла **for** устанавливается увеличения локальной переменной "i", и это значение записывается в массив. По окончанию цикла, этот массив возвращается. И уже в другой проге где нужно циклить, просто написать:

> `for (let i of range(**from**, **to**, **step**))`

Но потом, я узнал что в **JavaScript** есть оператор **yield**, который позволяет сделать генератор.  Я написал вторую версию своей функции **range** и результат не подвёл, всё одинаково. Вторая версия особо похожа на первую, просто в ней нет массива и возврата массива. Итого два кода, выполняющий свою работу с правильным и одинаковым итогом. Но какой из кодов больше предназначен для такой ситуации?

Первый код:

```
function range(from: number, to?: number, step?: number): number[] {
    to = to ? to : 75000000;
    step = step ? step : 1;

    let array: number[] = [];
    
    for (let i = from; i < to; i += step) {
        array.push(i)
    }

    return array;
}

export default range;
```

Второй код:

```
function* range(from: number, to?: number, step?: number) {
    to = to ? to : 75000000;
    step = step ? step : 1;

    for (let i = from; i < to; i += step) {
        yield i;
    }
}

export default range;
```

Comment: ну ты заморочился))

Comment: Себя надо заставить считать, что делаю что-то полезное :)

Comment: если нужен именно массив в результате - можно первый вариант, если нужно будет просто перебирать значения - второй вариант будет экономичней по памяти

Comment: @Grundy подходит второй вариант больше всего.

Comment: https://github.com/iter-tools/iter-tools/blob/v7.1.3/src/impls/range/range.js

Comment: Ваша функция не соответствует питоновской, там можно задать отрицательный step и to соответственно меньше from. Условие `i < to` у вас в циклах сработает неверно

Comment: @Mike спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Предложу такой, но он ближе к первому

```js
function range(from, to, step) {
  return Array.from({length: Math.ceil((to-from)/step)}, (_,i)=> i*step + from);
}

console.log(range(10,20, 1));
console.log(range(10,20, 2));
console.log(range(10,20, 3));

range(10,20, 3).forEach(item=>console.log(item));
```

Comment: а что не так со вторым вариантом?

Comment: @nörbörnën ничего Grundy ответил в коментариях

Comment: @nörbörnën просто больше логично сделать генератор чисел, вместо того, чтобы создавать новый массив, и проходиться по нему.

Comment: @A_Br2H ваша идея вполне симпатичная, но заметный эффект будет только на больших интервалах. но, как бы, мне вообще это обсуждение кажется немножко обсуждением вкуса фломастеров :) на мой вкус, например, в js нехватает perl-ового [loops with ranges](https://www.perl.com/article/17/2013/4/12/Perl-for-loops/#for-loops-with-ranges), шикарнее некуда

Comment: @nörbörnën так и есть вкусовщина. ничего против не имею

Comment: @nörbörnën Увидел диапазоны в Perl, попробую сделать. :)